# ActiveAdmin / Inherited Resources looking for invalid route when using nested resources. Only on server, not locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, inherited-resources

I have a Rails 4 app using ActiveAdmin and nested resources. Everything is working fine on my local development version, but when I deploy to a server (Ubuntu LTS 12.04) I'm having a problem.

I have an ActiveAdmin configuration like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This results in a path helper of `admin_user_order_path`. When trying to access the orders page (/admin/users/3/orders) I get an error saying route not valid, however it's looking for `admin_user_user_order_path` (note the additional `user`)

I've traced this back as far as I can, and I've found that at line 150 of [inherited_resources/class_methods.rb](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources/blob/master/lib/inherited_resources/class_methods.rb) `self.parents_symbols` already is `[:user]` - as a result, at line 167, it becomes `[:user, :user]` causing the problem.

So, as a **very temporary** solution, on the server I've manually added this at line 150:

```
self.parents_symbols = []
```

If I try the same thing locally (where it was otherwise working), that then breaks with a different error.

My mind is a bit fried now. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Which version of AcitveAdmin are you using? Also, it is possible to have strange side effects when models are named the same as ActiveRecords methods, in this case, `#order`.

Comment: I was using the rails4 branch, which I see now is no more. I've switched to master and it appears to be working now. My bad. Thanks for the pointer! At least I got to tour through inherited-resources.

Comment: I had, at least, checked that the same versions of gems were on both local and server, so still don't understand what was different, but hey, all working now!